# Error: await is only valid in async function when function is already within an async function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sha256

Goal: Get a list of files from my directory; get the SHA256 for each of those files

Error: `await is only valid in async function`

I'm not sure why that is the case since my function is already wrapped inside an async function.. any help is appreciated!

```
const hasha = require('hasha');

const getFiles = () => {
    fs.readdir('PATH_TO_FILE', (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(i => {
           return i;
        });
    });   
}
(async () => {
    const getAllFiles = getFiles()
    getAllFiles.forEach( i => {
        const hash = await hasha.fromFile(i, {algorithm: 'sha256'});
        return console.log(hash);
    })
});
```

Comment: Your `await` is inside the `.forEach()` callback which is NOT declared as `async`.  Also, `forEach()` is not promise-aware so it will run all your iterations in parallel.  If you switch your `.forEach()` to a plain  `for (let i of getAllFiles)` loop, both of the above issues will be fixed.

Comment: Also, `getFiles()` doesn't actually return anything so `const getAllFiles = getFiles()` will not work.  Again, you need to understand that `.forEach()` takes a separate callback and returning from it doesn't do anything to the parent function.

Comment: You can't use `forEach` with async-await (or at least, it won't work the way you probably want it to). Use a normal for loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `await` isn't inside an `async` function because it's inside the `.forEach()` callback which is not declared `async`.

You really need to rethink how you approach this because `getFiles()` isn't even returning anything.  Keep in mind that returning from a callback just returns from that callback, not from the parent function.

Here's what I would suggest:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const hasha = require('hasha');

async function getAllFiles() {
    let files = await fsp.readdir('PATH_TO_FILE');
    for (let file of files) {
        const hash = await hasha.fromFile(i, {algorithm: 'sha256'});
        console.log(hash);            
    }
}

getAllFiles().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

In this new implementation:

1. Use `const fsp = require('fs').promises` to get the promises interface for the `fs` module.
2. Use `await fsp.readdir()` to read the files using promises
3. Use a `for/of` loop so we can properly sequence our asynchronous operations with `await`.
4. Call the function and monitor both completion and error.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what didn't work in my code! your solution worked.