# Get List of all server files in a directory in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server

Any one here can help me out to rite a code to fetch List of all server files in a directory using Node.js

Just like it is done locally for system file

```
const testFolder = './models/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

Comment: how do you define server files ??

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by server files? `fs` should work the same on a server and on a local file system. They're both file systems.

Comment: Take a look at this answer from a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878086/error-await-is-only-valid-in-async-function-when-function-is-already-within-an/60878291#60878291

Comment: server file means files from other website just like web page name scraper

Comment: You'll need to be a bit clearer about that. Scraping webpages requires something like Cheerio. Reading files from another server requires hacking.

Comment: ok let be clear i need a reactjs code to fetch all the img file from any website link for eg:- "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img18/Ebooks/202003/Genres" in this file there are server image i need all the image file name "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img18/Ebooks/202003/Genres/Bio_S._SY116_CB420506992_.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to read all files present inside a directory.

```
 fs.readdirSync(`foldername`).forEach(function (file) {
  console.log(file);
 });
```

Comment: Moving from async FS operation to sync FS operation is a step down from OP's code, which appears to work fine. What's the benefit of this?

Comment: ok let be clear i need a reactjs code to fetch all the img file from any website link for eg:- "images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img18/Ebooks/202003/…" in this file there are server image i need all the image file name "images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img18/Ebooks/202003/…"

Comment: You should learn about cheerio for that. I don't know whether it runs on reactjs but surely runs on nodejs